# Python task from edX...again

Tags: python

This is the second time I will ask you for help regarding a task from the MIT edX class.

The task is:
A word is considered erician if it contains the letters e, r, i, and c in it, in that order. For example, we would say that the following words are erician: "meritocracy", "generic", "derrick", "euphoric", "heretic", and "electric", because they each contain those four letters in the correct order. The word "rice" is not erician because the four letters appear in the wrong order.

In this problem, we want you to write a more generalized function called x_ian(x, word) that returns True if all the letters of x are contained in word in the same order as they appear in x.

***This function has to be recursive! You may not use loops (for or while) to solve this problem.***

And here is my code for the function:

```
if x=="":
        return True
if len(x)>len(word):
        return False
if x==word:
    return True
elif (x[0]==word[0]):
    x_ian(x[1:],word[1:])
else:
    x_ian(x,word[1:])
```

I am currently at a loss why my function returns None, not True or False. I have worked with the debugger in IDLE on this and it finishes the execution with 
' main '.x_ian().line49: return True

Yet the function returns None.

Will appreciate any help.

Comment: Never mind, I just figured this out. Moderators, delete if you think it is appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

You need to return the output of your recursive calls:

```
elif (x[0]==word[0]):
    return x_ian(x[1:],word[1:])
else:
    return x_ian(x,word[1:])
```

otherwise python will simply reach the end of your function, which means it'll return `None`; the default return value for a function.

Your code could be simplified to:

```
def x_ian(x, word):
    if not x or x == word:
        return True
    if len(x) > len(word):
        return False
    if x[0]==word[0]:
        return x_ian(x[1:], word[1:])
    return x_ian(x, word[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a return of None because not all of your branches return a value. The two recursive calls need to return their results. Something like:

```
return x_ian(x[1:],word[1:])
```

If a function never calls return, then python implicitly returns None.

Answer (score 0):

Here, the `.index()` function can be quite handy. The `index()` function on a string will always return the index of the 1st occurrence of the letter you pass in as a parameter. So,

```
print 'abcdceg'.index('c') 
# will return 2 - the first occurrence of 'c' in the string
```

Making use of this, we will first check if the x[0] returns an index from the string like so

```
try:
   word.index(x[0])
except:
   # do something ...
```

If the 1st letter of x doesn't exist in the word at all, it will enter the exception. But, if it does return an index, we would want to trim this string from that 1st occurrence until the end of the word, and look for the successive letter in x, like so, as a recursive call:

```
x_ian(x[1:], word[word.index(x[0]) + 1:])
```

Now, if the string doesn't return an index, which means, there could be two possibilities, either x ran out of letters or, there is a letter in x that doesn't exist in the word. So, now we have are exception case:

```
try:
  word.index(x[0])
except:
  if len(x) == 0:
    return True
  else:
    return False
```

Putting it all together

```
def x_ian(x, word):   
    # the .index will always return the 1st occurance's index
    try:
        word.index(x[0])
    except:
        if len(x) == 0:
            # at this point, all the letters in x have been checked
            #  in successive order, which means, it exists.
            return True
        else:
            # at this point, we encountered a letter in x that doesn't
            #  exist in word.
            return False

    return x_ian(x[1:], word[word.index(x[0]) + 1:])
```

You can check out the running code [here](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def+x_ian(x,+word%29%3A%0D%0A++++%22%22%22%0D%0A++++Given+a+string+x,+returns+True+if+all+the+letters+in+x+are%0D%0A++++contained+in+word+in+the+same+order+as+they+appear+in+x.%0D%0A%0D%0A++++%3E%3E%3E+x_ian('eric',+'meritocracy'%29%0D%0A++++True%0D%0A++++%3E%3E%3E+x_ian('eric',+'cerium'%29%0D%0A++++False%0D%0A++++%3E%3E%3E+x_ian('john',+'mahjong'%29%0D%0A++++False%0D%0A++++%0D%0A++++x%3A+a+string%0D%0A++++word%3A+a+string%0D%0A++++returns%3A+True+if+word+is+x_ian,+False+otherwise%0D%0A++++%22%22%22%0D%0A++++%23%23%23TODO.%0D%0A%0D%0A++++%23base+case+is%0D%0A%0D%0A++++%23+the+.index+will+always+return+the+1st+occurance's+index%0D%0A++++%0D%0A++++try%3A%0D%0A++++++++word.index(x%5B0%5D%29%0D%0A++++except%3A%0D%0A++++++++if+len(x%29+%3D%3D+0%3A%0D%0A++++++++++++return+True%0D%0A++++++++else%3A%0D%0A++++++++++++return+False%0D%0A++++++++%0D%0A++++return+x_ian(x%5B1%3A%5D,+word%5Bword.index(x%5B0%5D%29%3A%5D%29%0D%0A++++%0D%0A++++%0D%0Aprint+x_ian('eric',+'ceriumc'%29&mode=edit&origin=opt-frontend.js&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&textReferences=false&py=2&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D).